# Tempo de cache expirando automático

Tags: c#, .net, cache

Estou usando a função abaixo para armazenar o cache estava funcionando normal, mas agora quando add o tempo de 60min é como se expirasse automático, agora se insiro um tempo maior como 181min o cache é mantido.

Se alguém puder me ajudar fico grata.

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(chave,
                valor,
                null,
                DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60),
                Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto pode dever-se a um problema com timezones.

Em vez de

```
DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60)
```

Prefira

```
DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60)
```